# Java Book or Website (like Cplusplus.com) for C++ programmers to learn java very fast

Tags: java, android, c++

I am looking for a book which teaches Java very fast. Basically I am a C++ programmer and do not need to know each and every aspect of programming. I am learning java for android apps development. A lot of books like thinking in Java, learning java and others suggested are pretty big  and I want something small to get me going.
A website like http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ for java also can be helpful. please answer ASAP.

Comment: Very Fast. Define in how may days you want to learn Java ASAP.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Comment: Might help you [link](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/java-tutorial/).

Comment: Since you're keen to start developing in Android, start [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/index.html).

Comment: One thing to watch out for: *don't* try to treat Java as if it's C++. Some of the nastiest Java code I've seen was from C++ programmers who tried to speak Java with a C++ accent.

Comment: @Jon: and the converse is true as well ;) It applies to every language out there.

Comment: @Martinho: Oh I'm sure - C++ to Java is just the place *I've* happened to see it most.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I love to think of the javadoc as the equivalent of cplusplus.com. The comments on standard classes are much more detailed than stl comments are (and the code is a lot easier to read, too)

Personally I'd recommend just reading a tiny bit of literature and then using an IDE that provides really quick access to code and comments for any callable method (almost all do if you link sources and javadoc). Usually they provide greate usage exmaples and the code itself teaches best practices and proper design.

Unlinke for C / C++ I don't think using an IDE is much of a problem. Javac hides everything anyway and there is not much to know about something like linking unless you use a lot of libraries and enter "jar hell". But even then there is nothing to be learned by compiling from the shell that might help.

Build scripts to use will most probably ant or maven and both are a lot more high-level than Makefiles. While I'd really recommend never to rely on an IDE for C++, I'd totally do so for java.

Comment: I agree. I started with C++ using cplusplus.com. I loved the way it is written for quick learner. I also expect something like that. I have not found it yet. If any of you know please add the link here.

Answer (score 0):

What about Beginning Android 3 (http://www.apress.com/9781430232971) 
It has 612 Pages but it really focuses on Android development and not really on programming basics.

Check the Table of Contents on that page and you will see.

Answer (score 0):

[Head First Java](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596004651) is a great book and very easy to read and understand. It got lots of graphics to support the reading. I find it perfect for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

For pure java - Thinking in java (its nicely written but quite big (+1000pages))
For Android check notepad tutorial on official android page its good for beggining http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html

Comment: I bought this book. It is a good book but not a book to learn Java fast. But, yes majority of forums recommend this book.